# Java Generics - method not applicable to Mockito generated stub

Tags: java, generics, mockito

I've got a `ThingsProvider` interface I'm trying to test with Mockito, (simplified version) defined as follows:

```
interface ThingsProvider {
    Iterable<? extends Thing> getThings()
}
```

Now when I'm going to test it with Mockito, I'm doing the following (again, simplified for the question):

```
ThingsProvider thingsProvider = mock(ThingsProvider.class);
List<Thing> things = Arrays.asList(mock(Thing.class));
when(thingsProvider.getThings()).thenReturn(things); // PROBLEM IS HERE
```

**Compile error message: `The method thenReturn(Iterable<capture#11-of ? extends Thing>) in the type OngoingStubbing<Iterable<capture#11-of ? extends Thing>> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Thing>)`**

Now, purely for getting the test going, I'm changing the last line to

```
when(thingsProvider.getThings()).thenReturn((List)things); // HAHA take THAT generics!
```

... but this would clearly be bad to do in non-testing code.

**My question(s):**

1. Why is this an error? I'm clearly returning objects that extend `Thing`, which is what the interface expects.
2. Is there a better way of solving this? Perhaps defining my interface differently? I haven't run into this issue outside of testing so far...

On #2 - The main reason I'm not simply returning `Iterable<Thing>` is that there are several different extensions where the concrete types have things buried in them that return specific subtypes, and I end up with issues like `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Iterable<MagicalThing> to Iterable<Thing>` - maybe the solution is a better way to fix *this* issue?

---

For those of you less familiar with Mockito, a more pure Java version of #1 is below:

```
public static void main(String...args) {
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
    blah(ints);

    Foo<Number> foo1 = new Foo<Number>();
    foo1.bar(ints);  // This works

    Foo<? extends Number> foo2 = new Foo<Number>();
    foo2.bar(ints);  // NO COMPILEY!
} 

private static void blah(List<? extends Number> numberList) {
    // something
}

public static class Foo<T> {
    public Object bar(List<? extends T> tList) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try `Mockito.<Iterable<? extends Thing>>when(thingsProvider.getThings())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard in return type is very convenient for subclass implementations, as you've observed.

It doesn't make much difference to the callers of the method though; you may change it to `Iterable<Thing>` if you'd like to; it's simpler on javadoc, at the expense of subclass implementers. Subclass can do brute cast if necessary, e.g. `List<MyThing> => Iterable<Thing>`, thanks to erasure.

---

The reason for your problem is wildcard capture; basically every expression goes though wildcard capture first before the contextual expression is evaluated. In a method invocation

```
    foo( arg )
```

`arg` is always wildcard-captured first, before method applicability/overloading/inference are done. In your case, the more general type `Iterable<? extends Thing>` is lost, becomes `Iterable<CAP#>`.

Usually, wildcard capture does not pose any problem; but Mockito semantics is nothing usual.

---

The first solution is to avoid type inference; explicitly supply type arguments instead

```
Mockito.<Iterable<? extends Thing>>when(...
```

Or as Delimanolis suggested, use a target type to restrict inference (in java8+)

```
OngoingStubbing<Iterable<? extends Thing>> stub =  when(...
```

---

It also appears that lambda inference may be helpful for this case

```
static <T> OngoingStubbing<T> whenX( Supplier<T> sup )
{    
    return Mockito.when( sup.get() );
}

whenX(thingsProvider::getThings).thenReturn(things);
// T = Iterable<? extends Thing>
```

---

And - if your interface is simple enough, just directly implement it instead of mock it :)

```
List<Thing> things = ...;

ThingsProvider thingsProvider = ()->things;
```

Answer (score 3):

Refactor into two steps

```
OngoingStubbing<Iterable<? extends Thing>> stub =  when(thingsProvider.getThings());
stub.thenReturn(things);
```

or use what [bayou.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991884/java-generics-method-not-applicable-to-mockito-generated-stub/30991988#comment50013501_30991884) suggested

```
Mockito.<Iterable<? extends Thing>>when(thingsProvider.getThings())
```

Comment: Hm, interesting alternative workaround! Not necessarily better than my current workaround outlined in the question though due to the type safety issue...

Comment: @Chris Did you mean before the edit? Yeah, type safety not great. I didn't like the solution so removed answer.

Comment: Yeah, was referring to the original answer in my above comment. I'll take a closer look at the revised version in a bit. Thx for the update!